# Nested forms with additional data from an unrelated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Perhaps I'm overthinking this, but I want to be able to use a nested form that depends on the data that's coming from another table. Let me elaborate.

I have 4 tables with something like the following pseudo-code:

```
 Product
    has_many: providers

 Provider
    belongs_to: product

 Sale
    has_many: products
    has_many: orders
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders

 Order
    belongs_to: sale
```

So far, so good.

My problem begins when I'm trying to make a Sale. Each Product will have an X amount of Providers (usually 4), and each Sale will always have an Order for each of those Providers (even if it's 0), so I need the data of each Provider so I can specify how much I'm ordering from each.

I have something like this:

```
=form_for @sale do |s|
     =s.label :date, 'Date'
     =s.text_field :date
     =s.label :other, 'Other Information'
     =s.text_area :other
     =s.object.product.providers.each do |p|
          =s.fields_for :orders do |o|
               =p.name
               =o.label :amount, 'Amount'
               =o.text_field :amount
```

This doesn't work. What this is achieving is obtaining the amount of Providers of each Product, and listing the name of each Provider - so far, so good - but I need to specify the amount of that each one is going to receive in the Order. If there's data, the text_field will get populated with the very first record that gets matched in Orders, but since I'm looping through it, the same data is also populated for the remaining 3.

I know my logic is flawed (I've been battling through it for the last 4 hours). I think it is a matter of going back to the drawing board (which I'm doing right now), but I wanted to see if anybody could maybe see the obvious.

What I'd like to see is something like this:

```
 |--Provider Name--|---Amount----|
 |-----------------|-------------|
 | Provider One    |     10      |
 | Provider Two    |      2      |
 | Provider Three  |      0      |
 | Provider Four   |      4      |
 |-----------------|-------------|
```

Where the "amount" on each line is a text_field for the Amount field of the form. Initially, the text_fields should come out empty, so I can fill them in with data. Once they have data, they should pop back with the previous data used. Pretty standard.

I thought about creating those x amount of records on the Orders table as soon as I visited the new Sale page, but that'd make me fill the Order table with lots of unused data. That approach would also hinder it later, if for some reason a new Provider is added.

I don't know how to proceed, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an FYI, one of your associations should be `belongs_to: product` instead of `belongs_to: products`. `Belongs_to` is pretty much saying,  I am related to exactly one of these products, and I have the foreign key for it.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks. It's pseudo-code though, those aren't the real tables. I'm just having a hard explaining it, and that relationship was the best I could come up with, haha. It is on its singular form in my project, obviously, but thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for list of text_fields for orders:

```
=form_for @sale do |s|
 =s.label :date, 'Date'
 =s.text_field :date
 =s.label :other, 'Other Information'
 =s.text_area :other
 =s.products.each do |product|
   =product.providers.each do |provide|
      =p.name
      =s.fields_for :orders do |o|
           =o.label :amount, 'Amount'
           =o.text_field :amount
```